# Link class and script source meaning

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<head>
<title>Image Crop</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.form.js"></script>
//ajax
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
```

I have these these in my codes, and i don't really understand what is it for?( the codes on top)Is there a need to include these codes ?

Comment: Can you please give more detail and background information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class in `<link>` really has no significance. It is probably there to access it easier from JavaScript. In general, classes are used to apply CSS properties from a stylesheet, but a link doesn't display visually.

The source of a script file is the url that your browser should get that script file from.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.form.js">`

will load a JavaScript file from the file `jquery.form.js` in your root directory.

Comment: So i can remove the '<link>' class?

Comment: Yes, unless you are referencing the link from javascript using that class.